# Check to see if a web part exists on a page using SPLimitedWebPartManager

Tags: web-part

In a feature I need to check if a part is already on the page.

How can this be performed (programatically) (i.e. through a feature)

thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
if (manager != null)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart webpart in manager.WebParts)
    {
        if (webpart.Title == "some title")
        {
            // Web Part found!

            break;
        }
    }
}
```